# How server ensures mobile application is running in TEE?

Tags: cryptography, mobile

TEE (Trusted execution environment) facilitates secure execution environment for a trusted app. A device can be running both trusted applications and normal applications.

How can/ does a server verifies that mobile application is running as a trusted application in TEE and not as a normal application in rich execution environment?

Comment: Client can make API calls to check if the TEE support is available on the device and the results of the API call can be communicated to server over HTTP.